# Why does continuous Bayesian analysis seem to give this contradictory result?

Tags: bayesian, inference

Let's say you have a process that generates data according to r = sin(t) + epsilon, where epsilon ~ N(0,V) is Gaussian noise. The unconditional variance of r is 0.5 + V.

Let's say we're forecasting r with a model m, and that our forecast is "perfect" in that m = sin(t). Construct v = r - m, which is the forecast error, and will be ~ N(0,V).

According to Bayes, we then have p(r|v) ~ p(v|r)*p(r), which is the the product of two Gaussian PDFs, one with variance V, the other (0.5+V). This product will itself be a Gaussian with total variance T = 1/(1/V + 1/(0.5+V)).

The funny thing is that T < V guaranteed, in fact T/V = (V+0.5)/(2V+0.5)! In other words, according to Bayes, the variance of your forecast error is less than the inherent noise in the data generation process itself!?! Isn't that impossible? Can anyone help me sort through this?

Thank you in advance,
-Jesse

---

whuber, 
a derivation of the product of two Gaussian pdfs is from https://people.ok.ubc.ca/jbobowsk/phys327/Gaussian%20Convolution.pdf. The formula for the variance I gave, 1 / (1 / (V+0.5) + 1/V) seems to be accurate. Another way of writing this same expression is V*(V+0.5)/(V + (V + 0.5)) from which my equation for T/V follows directly - showing that T < V.

Perhaps you were citing the variance for the convolution of two Gaussian pdfs? The sum of the variances is correct for the convolution. I believe Bayes specifies the product, not the convolution, however, or do I have that wrong?

Comment: How do you get that $Dr_t=\frac{1}{2}+V$? It is clear that $Er_t=\sin t$, since $\varepsilon\sim N(0,V)$, then $Dr_t=E(r_t-Er_t)^2=E(r_t-\sin t)=E\varepsilon^2=D\varepsilon=V$.

Comment: I believe 'unconditional' here means that $t$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi]$ and independent of $\epsilon$.

Comment: correct, E(r) = 0 when taken over t

Comment: If $t$ is uniform, then $p(v|r)=p(\varepsilon)$ is Gaussian, but $p(r)$ is definitely not. Maybe that is your problem.

Comment: @Jesse "This product will itself be a Gaussian with total variance T = 1/(1/V + 1/(0.5+V))."  Where does this come from?  If V and 0.5+V are variances, then T should be their *sum*.  If V and 0.5+V are precisions, then this formula gives the *precision," which--of course--goes down.

Comment: That reference is merely an exercise in completing the square.  Its "product" of Gaussians multiplies two functions *of a single variable* (x)--it is neither a product of random variables nor a convolution.  I don't see how it's relevant.  What's really confusing is the OP's assertion that "The unconditional variance of r is 0.5 + V", because this seems to imply that t is a random variable.  What is its distribution?  Regardless, when t is random it's unlikely that r has a Gaussian distribution at all.

Comment: @mpiktas You should post your comment as a solution.  (There are other problems with the calculation in question, but this one alone demonstrates it is invalid.)

Comment: whuber, thank you. you point out a problem that mpitkas also pointed out which is that r is not Gaussian. the simplified version of the problem, where r = c + epsilon, epsilon ~ N(0,V) does have r as Gaussian, and still would have fallen prey to the rest of my argument. It looks like there is a second root problem, however, which luispedro points out which I believe to be the ultimate cause of my misunderstanding. although clearly, I had plenty of misunderstanding to go around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the variances are zero: $V(v|r) = V(r|v) = 0$.$p(v|r)$ is a Dyrac function which has a peak at the right spot (where $r = v -m$).

If you know $v$ or $r$, the other one is a deterministic function of the one you know.

Comment: i don't follow on how p(v|r) = 0, wont the epsilon noise term in r mean that there is uncertainty in v even when you know r and m? even more specifically wont p(v|r) be exactly and only the noise term in r and thus p(v|r) ~ N(0,V)?

Comment: Sorry, got my notation messed up. Fixed now.

Comment: luispedro, I believe your answer is correct. my misunderstanding was in thinking that p(v|r) was a Gaussian, but it is not, as you point out, and so the rest of my "solution" is invalid. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 5):

As per whuber's suggestion, I am posting the summary of mistakes in a separate answer.

1. The distribution of $t$ is not stated. If $t$ is not a random variable, then the mean of $r$ is $\sin t$ and unconditional variance hence is $V$, not $\frac{1}{2}+V$.
2. If we assume that $t$ is uniformly distributed in interval $[0,2\pi]$ and independent from $\varepsilon$ as per shabbychef suggestion, then unconditional variance is $\frac{1}{2}+V$. But then distribution of $r$ is certainly not normal. So the product of $p(v|r)$ and $p(r)$ will not be Gaussian, and following variance calculations are incorrect.

Comment: mpiktas,
actually, if you set r = c + epsilon with c a constant, you get the same problem. In fact, that is a simpler statement of this issue. In that case p(r|v) will have a variance exactly half of the variance of epsilon.